How to copy two rows of data into one column and delete duplicates
Need assistance on copying two rows of data into one and delete duplicates - The data begins in  column B4 & L4. I would like to copy both columns starting at cell E4. Thereafter, I will need to delete duplicates.
Sub Delete_duplicates()

' Delete_duplicates Macro

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRowB As Long
Dim lastRowL As Long
Dim lastRowE As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PS  Analysis")

' Find the last row with data in column B and column L

lastRowB = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

lastRowL = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row

ws.Range("B3").Copy

Destination = ws.Range("B4:B" & lastRowB)

ws.Range("L3").Copy

Destination = ws.Range("L4:B" & lastRowB) 

' FInd the last row in column E to start copying the data

lastRowE = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row + 1

' Copy bpth columns B  & L starting at E4
 
ws.Range("B4:B" & lastRowB).Copy

Destination = ws.Range("E4")

ws.Range("L4:L" & lastRowL).Copy

Destination = ws.Cells(lastRowE, "E")
 
End Sub


How about remove duplicates after pasting?

Where is a sample of your data that demonstrates the problem you are having? Make up data that demonstrates the problem if you need to avoid sharing confidential information. And why VBA? This would seem to be doable with a formula.

Option Explicit

Sub Delete_duplicates()

    ' Delete_duplicates Macro
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRowB As Long, lastRowL As Long, lastRowE As Long
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PS  Analysis")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ws
        ' Find the last row with data in column B copy to E
        lastRowB = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("B4:B" & lastRowB).Copy .Range("E4")
        
        ' Find the last row with data in column L copy to E
        lastRowE = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
        lastRowL = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("L4:L" & lastRowL).Copy .Range("E" & lastRowE + 1)
        
        ' remove duplicates in column E
        lastRowE = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("E4:E" & lastRowE).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 
End Sub

